# Postulate of wave function collapse and entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-entanglement, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Can we say that a measurement on a system of $k$ entangled particles is the cause of the [collapse of the wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse) into $k$th states simultaneously?

Comment: There is no such thing as a collapse of the wave function. A wave function is the description of a quantum mechanical ensemble. It always stays the same, no matter what the outcome of an individual measurement is. Entanglement is simply the consequence of local symmetries like angular momentum conservation for a quantum system.

Comment: I have rephrased my question

Comment: Just a small remark regarding entanglement: It isn't particles that are entangled, but rather quantum modes that they excite. One could very well have a photon entangled with the vacuum. It may seem like a small remark but it makes a world of difference in understanding that the excitations themselves aren't the carriers of entanglement. (Cf. for example, teleportation schemes with a single photon.)

Comment: Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @FlatterMann this is a bit of a confusing statement because in popular science 'collapse of the wavefunction' is very much a thing and it is used in many introductory textbooks. Maybe you could elaborate how it relates to this textbook-way of viewing things

Comment: @FlatterMann Of course there is such a thing: the concept comes directly from experiment. That's physics. You can come up with an elaborate rationalization, but that's not physics: it's mathematics.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Popular science is wrong about a great many things and so are many introductory textbooks. Part of the difference between a layperson and a professional is that a professional knows that not even textbooks are perfect and he/she can successfully find errors in them if they exist.

Comment: @JohnDoty I, or better my detectors, have measured many trillions of quanta and not once did a wave function collapse. The only thing that ever happened is that a little bit of energy, aka a quantum, got transferred irreversibly from a quantum field into an external system called "a detector". You are welcome to point me to a type of experiment that can collapse wave functions. I have never seen one, not at CERN and not in any other lab I ever set foot in.

Comment: @FlatterMann That's your mathematical *interpretation*. What experiment can you perform to demonstrate that collapse *doesn't* happen?

Comment: @JohnDoty I don't do math. I am an experimentalist. As such I know when I am dealing with energy, which is all the time. I never deal with wave functions. They exist exclusively on paper.

Comment: @FlatterMann An experimentalist should understand that asserting the truth of a model, especially when a different model makes the same predictions, is not physics.

Comment: @JohnDoty It is unfortunate that you are arguing for arguments sake. Let's end it here. You are clearly out of sensible replies. Please take care.

Comment: @FlatterMann You assert that wavefunction collapse, a concept with a long and productive history, doesn't happen, and then you accuse *me* of arguing for argument's sake?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139695/discussion-between-flattermann-and-john-doty).

Comment: @FlatterMann I understand what you're saying but my point is that simply refuting something that is 'generally accepted' (I put generally accepted in quotes on purpose) is confusing for someone reading this. Are the textbooks wrong? Is this random comment on the internet wrong? It would be better to put this in context, for example: many introductory textbooks say wavefunction collapse is X, however I think this is not the case because of Y.

Answer (score 1):

The following state is the GHZ entangled state for 3 particles:
$$|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)$$
where each ket $|q_1q_2q_3\rangle$ represents the state of the first, second and third particle in that order. In this case, the particles that can only be in two states $0$ or $1$.

If you measure (or "collapse") one of the particles in the GHZ state (in the basis given above), you will know the state of the other two. For example, if you measure the first particle to be in state $0$, you know already that particles #2 and #3 are also in state $0$.

Now if you have a W entangled state, such as:
$$|\mathrm{W}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|100\rangle),$$
measuring the state of a single particle will not necessarily disentangle the other particles. Example: Let us say that you collapse the first particle and you measure $0$, then the other two particles remain maximally entangled in the following Bell state:
$$|\Psi^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle).$$

So no, collapsing the state of a single particle does not necessarily disentangle (or "collapse") the rest (in this basis).

Comment: A minor comment that might be interesting to the OP: In the GHZ state as well, if you measure one of the particles in the $\vert \pm\rangle$ basis, the other two particles will be left in the maximally entangled Bell state $\vert{00}\rangle\pm\vert{11}\rangle$.